# I can't figure out why hash[0] is being assigned the value 1 in the output . Any help would be appreciated

Tags: c++, arrays

This is my code:-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string magazine="aab";
    string ransomNote="aa";
    int hash[123]={};
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<=magazine.length();i++)
        {
            hash[magazine[i]]++;
        }
        for(i=0;i<123;i++)
        {
            cout<<hash[i]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
}
```

The output is:-

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: for(i=0;i<=magazine.length();i++) its because of the <= part of this for loop.

Comment: The string is 0-terminated and since you read past the last char, you read the terminating 0 on the last loop iteration.

Comment: `for(i=0;i<=magazine.length();i++) { hash[magazine[i]]++; }` could be `for(char mag:magazine) { hash[mag]++; }` If the compiler messes up the indexing, you'll have an interesting story to tell. To other programmers, at any rate.

Comment: `int hash[123]={};` and `for(i=0;i<123;i++)` avoid the [Magic Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad). It sucks to change one and forget to change the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In c++ chars are *almost* the same thing as integers and they are stored as integers. So when you are performing `hash[magazine[i]]++;` what really happens is that the `magazine[3]` (which is the NULL character) will be promoted to an int (Source: [cpp reference: Implicit Conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion), the equivalent of which is 0 based on the [cpp reference: ASCII codes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii).

Thus, the statement `hash[3] = 0` is `true`.
That said, the below code which is similar to the code used in the example

```
string x = hash[magazine[3]]++; //first x is assigned with the value of hash[magazine[3]], then hash[magazine[3]] is incremented.
cout << "output: " << x << "\n";
```

will produce `output: 0`.

That happens because the `hash[0]` is assigned with the value of `hash[magazine[3]]` *before* the increment operator.Equivalently, the increment (++ operator) will be evaluated *after* the rest of the expression is -- after the assignment has been done.

If you want to avoid this behavior, you can do the below:

```
string x = ++hash[magazine[3]]; //first hash[magazine[0]] is incremented, then it is assigned to x.
cout << "output: " << x << "\n";
```

which will produce `output: 1`.

However, `hash[magazine[i]]++` is inside a *loop*. This means that **after the loop concludes**, the expression has already been evaluated and the hash array contains the new values, thus, `hash[0]` will be equal to `1`.

Cheers,

Comment: "what really happens is that the magazine[0] = 'a' (which is a char) will be promoted to an int (Source: cpp reference: Implicit Conversions, the equivalent of which is 0 based on the cpp reference: ASCII codes." . I get that. But the int value of  'a' is 97 ( according to ASCII). How is the int equivalent of 'a' zero(0) ?

Comment: @ShwetanshSharma updated my answer. In c++ empty array initializations will also initialize elements as 0.
However, the correction that has been made is that when the loop reaches magazine[3], will read the NULL character which is equivalent to 0, thus hash[0] will be 1.